# iterate over several collections in parallel

Tags: python, class, loops, object, for-loop

I am trying to create a list of objects (from a class defined earlier) through a loop. The structure looks something like:

```
ticker_symbols = ["AZN", "AAPL", "YHOO"]
stock_list = []  
for i in ticker_symbols:                                                             
    stock = Share(i)                                                                        
    pe = stock.get_price_earnings_ratio()                                            
    ps = stock.get_price_sales()                                                     
stock_object = Company(pe, ps)                     
stock_list.append(stock_object)
```

I would however want to add one more attribute to the Company-objects (stock_object) through the loop. The attribute would be a value from another list, like (arbitrary numbers) [5, 10, 20] where the first attribute would go to the first object, the second to the second object etc.Is it possible to do something like:

```
for i, j in ticker_symbols, list2:
    #dostuff
```

? Could not get this sort of nested loop to work on my own. Thankful for any help.

Comment: `for i, j in zip(ticker_symbols, list2):` - now you are ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for i, j in zip(ticker_symbols, list2):
```

Or

```
for (k, i) in enumerate(ticker_symbols):
    j = list2[k]
```

Equivalently:

```
for index in range(len(ticker_symbols)):
    i = ticker_symbols[index]
    j = list2[index]
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that all you have to do is change the for loop.
Instead of "for i in ticker_symbols:" you should loop like
"for i in range(len(ticker_symbols))" and then use the index i to do whatever you want with the second list.

```
ticker_symbols = ["AZN", "AAPL", "YHOO"]
stock_list = []  
for i in range(len(ticker_symbols):
    stock = Share(ticker_symbols[i])
    pe = stock.get_price_earnings_ratio()
    ps = stock.get_price_sales()
    # And then you can write
    px = whatever list2[i]
    stock_object = Company(pe, ps, px)
    stock_list.append(stock_object)
```

Some people say that using index to iterate is not good practice, but I don't think so specially if the code works.

Comment: Iterating though the index is discouraged in python (unless there is a specific reason), and there is much better ways to achieve the same goal.